# Is there a way to remove the newline created between an NSMutableDictionary key/object pair when writing to a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nscharacterset

I'm trying to make the entries in my `NSMutableDictionary` look like this when written to a file:

```
        <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>686</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Poetic Justice (Feat. Drake)</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Kendrick Lamar</string>
        <key>Album</key><string>Good Kid M.A.A.D City-(Deluxe Edition)</string>
        </dict>
```

Here's what my file looks like now:

```
        <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key>
        <integer>686</integer>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Poetic Justice (Feat. Drake)</string>
        <key>Artist</key>
        <string>Kendrick Lamar</string>
        <key>Album</key>
        <string>Good Kid M.A.A.D City-(Deluxe Edition)</string>
        </dict>
```

I have tried trimming the whitespace and newlines from the key strings and objects using `NSCharacterSet` like this

```
        NSString *trimmedArtistString = [ArtistString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

But that didn't work.
Can this be done?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: I'm trying to fix the structure of my file at the point that it gets written so I don't have to go messing with my file parser which already works with the structure that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: When you call `NSDictionary writeToFile` you have no control over the output. It's only meant to be re-parsed by the `NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` method. If you wish to write the contents of the dictionary to a file in a specific format then write your own code to write out the file. Don't use `writeToFile:`.

Comment: I figured that might be the case, thanks rmaddy.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the XML playlist files exported from iTunes, which don't insert a newline.